# Can't use TFS 2015 RestApi in Powershell using 'Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient' with Powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs

I'm trying to create a powershell module to interact with the new Rest Api using Powershell 3 and the assemblies from the Nuget Packages 'Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient' 
15.104.0-preview    641 Monday, August 22, 2016

Some more modules are also installed from that one.

I did a basic test and after I loaded the assemblies with Add-Type i have the following assemblies loaded.

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common - 15.104.25618.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi - 15.104.25618.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client - 15.104.25618.0
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common - 15.104.25618.0
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client - 15.104.25618.0
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client - 15.104.25618.0
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client - 15.104.25618.0
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client - 15.104.25618.0
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common - 15.104.25618.0
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi - 15.104.25618.0
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi - 15.104.25618.0
Newtonsoft.Json - 8.0.3.19514
System.Web.Http - 5.2.20826.0
```

In order to load System.Web.Http I have to load Newtonsoft.Json.dll version 6.0.8

```
Add-Type -Path 'D:\Temp\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.8\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
```

After I loaded all the dll I tried to create a BuildHttpClien and I get an error.

```
$cre = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssCredentials' -ArgumentList (Get-Credential)
$build = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClient' -ArgumentList ([uri]'{TfsCollectionUrl}'),$cre
```

when I run this code, I got the following error

```
Method not found: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.get_SerializerSettings()'. (raised by: New-Object)
```

I tried the above code in Powershell ISE in Powershell 3.0 compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The "System.Net.Http.Formatting" and "Newtonsoft.Json" is available in [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/5.2.2) package. To fix the error you get, you can installed this nuget package and then load these two reference from PowerShell.

```
Add-Type -Path 'D:\Temp\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.2\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'D:\Temp\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
```

Answer (score 0):

Nuget Packages 'Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient' 15.104.0-preview is a prerelease version of Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client. It's suggested to use the latest stable version [14.102.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/14.102.0).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Highlight the prerelease should ne be used. It turn out it support API Call for Higher version of TFS than TFS 2015.2 (Some API call use Version 3)

I used the following Nuget Packages. Download them and Copy all the *.dll in a single folder.

```
id                                                version       
--                                                -------       
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client                    5.2.2         
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core                      5.2.2         
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory   2.22.302111727
Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client             14.102.0      
Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient     14.102.0      
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client            14.102.0      
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient 14.102.0      
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager       1.7.0.0       
Newtonsoft.Json                                   6.0.8         
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt                   4.0.0         
WindowsAzure.ServiceBus                           2.5.1.0
```

I added the types only from some selected .dll that I put in a list and in a specific order. That seam to be a key part. NewtonSoft.Json is now in first and that work.

```
Name             Assembly                                        
----             --------                                        
NewtonJson       Newtonsoft.Json                                 
IdentityModel    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 
VSCommon         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common          
VSCommonWebApi   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi          
TFCommon         Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common                 
TFClient         Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client                 
VCClient         Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client  
WITClient        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client
BuildClient      Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client           
BuildCommon      Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common           
Build2           Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi          
DistributedTask  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi
```

After all of that, I'm able to created some basic types and start my journey into the TFS 2015 Rest web Api .

```
$credential = [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssCredentials]::new($true)

    PromptType Federated Windows                                                  Storage
    ---------- --------- -------                                                  -------
PromptIfNeeded           Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential        

$buildhttpclient = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildHttpClient]::new($tfscollectionuri,$credential)

$buildhttpclient.GetBuildsAsync('TEAMPROJECTNAME')



Result                 : {31221, 31220, 31219, 31218...}
Id                     : 165004
Exception              : 
Status                 : RanToCompletion
IsCanceled             : False
IsCompleted            : True
CreationOptions        : None
AsyncState             : 
IsFaulted              : False
AsyncWaitHandle        : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
CompletedSynchronously : False
```

Into the Result property are the builds.

NOTE: It look the Rest Api limit the number of build result to 1000's.
Still digging around to get more.